# C++ class object default constructor bug

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, getter-setter

I am trying to create a class object s2 with some customized attributes and some attributes from default constructor however my output is the wrong output for the get_year function. It should be outputing 0 which is the key for FRESHMAN but it is out putting 2 instead. The rest of the code is outputting as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
#include <iterator> // for std::begin, std::end
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;


enum year {FRESHMAN, SOPHOMORE, JUNIOR, SENIOR};
struct name
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const name& input)
    {
        os << input.firstName << ' ' << input.lastName << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};
class Student: name{

    private:
        name Name;
        year Year;
        int idNumber;
        string Department;


    
    
    




    public:
    void setname(string fn="", string ln="")
    {
        Name.firstName =fn;
        Name.lastName =ln;
    }
    name get_name()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    void set_year(year yr=FRESHMAN)
    {
        Year=yr;
    }
    year get_year()
    {
        return Year;
    }
    void set_ID(int ID=0)
    {
        idNumber=ID;
    }
    int get_ID()
    {
        return idNumber;
    }
    void set_Department(string Dept="")
    {
        Department=Dept;
    }
    string get_Department()
    {
        return Department;
    }

};
int main()
{
    Student s2;
    s2.setname("Nikolai", "Khabeboolin");
    s2.set_ID(12436193);

    cout<<"ID is: "<< s2.get_ID()<<", name is "<< s2.get_name()<<", year in school is: "<<s2.get_year()<<", Department is "<<s2.get_Department()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `enum class` counts as a class type and therefore default initialization does nothing. You should write `year Year{FRESHMAN};` and `int idNumber{-1};` so a `Student` is never uninitialized. A constructor requiring an `idNumber` and `Name` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Student` lacks a constructor, so all its members are default initialized, and the default initialization of `year Year` and `int idNumber` is "no initialization", so reading from them is undefined behavior. Reading them might find 0, 2, a random value each time, or crash.

I see that your class contains a `void set_year(year yr=FRESHMAN)` member, but your code never called `set_year`, so no part of this executed.

You should make a default constructor for `Student`, or as [Goswin von Brederlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4262344/goswin-von-brederlow) stated, use `year Year{FRESHMAN};` and `int idNumber{-1};` when declaring the members, to give them default initializations.

Answer (score 0):

By not explicitly declaring and defining a constructor, in this case `Student()`, you open yourself up to undefined behavior. Your constructor should call `set_year(year yr=FRESHMAN`) OR even better, just set the year itself.